# convert qr code into a pdf file

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently developing a system that can load csv file to mysql db, generate qr code using the saved data in mysql and display all the saved qr codes in a tabular format in my web page. I am able to do all the above, but I would like to know how I would go about converting that tabular fomatted data to a pdf file by the click of a button.  This is my code:

```
         <?php

         $servername = "localhost";
         $username = "root";
         $password = "";
         $dbname = "mydb";

         include("qrlib.php");

         // Create connection
         $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
          // Check connection
         if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
         } 

         //if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
         $result = $conn->query($sql);

         echo "<form><table border='1'>"; 


         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //echo "name: " . $row["name"]. " - email: " . $row["email"]. " " .   $row["phone"]. "<br>" ;

        //set it to writable location, a place for temp generated PNG files
        //$PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

       $PNG_TEMP_DIR = "qrcodes";


      //html PNG location prefix
      $PNG_WEB_DIR = 'temp/';

      //include "pdf.php";

      //ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
       if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
        mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);


    $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.$row["name"].'.png';

    //processing form input
    //remember to sanitize user input in real-life solution !!!
    $errorCorrectionLevel = 'L';
    $matrixPointSize = 4;

    // user data
    $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.$row["name"].'.png';


    echo $filename;


    QRcode::png($row["name"], $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2); 


    echo "<tr><td>
    <img src='$filename'></td></tr>";


     }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
   }

    echo "
   </table>
    </form>";

   //}
   $conn->close();

   ?>
```

Comment: If you can render HTML there's many tools that will wrangle HTML into a PDF. Otherwise you'll have to draw the PDF yourself. In either case, that's a project you'll have to spend considerable time on, there's no easy answer.

Comment: yea i did nd it worked out fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php library: [tcpdf](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF)
It can generate QR codes and then put them in PDF file in your desired format.

This is the link of an example using it:
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_050/